# Spring Validation Error Generation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using JSR-303 for validation and the Spring MVC 3. Validation is done manually through `validator.validate(bean, errors)` in a controller.

I annotated the `name` property of the `Foo` class with `@NotNull`. When the validation fails, I noticed that the Spring MVC generated the following error codes in the `Errors` object.

```
NotNull.form.foo.name
NotNull.name
NotNull.java.lang.String
NotNull
```

The way the `<form:errors>` tag works is that it will go through all the error codes and look up the default resource bundle until it returns a non-null message. Is there any way to customize these error codes or at least the order they are listed?

The reason is that I have a custom `ResourceBundle` object that returns a default message derived from a given message code if none is found in a resource bundle text file. Because the tag works its way down on the error code list, it will look up `NotNull.form.foo.name` first in this example. The text file of course does not have this entry, so the custom ResourceBundle object will return a default message. The problem is, I already have a message defined in the text file for `NotNull`, but the tag will see this as it stands.

If I could somehow generate only one error code, or reverse the order of the error codes, it would work.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe any of the solutions below work without this:  <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" /> in your spring setup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could not find simpler solution than this one...

**my-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="handlerAdapter" class="org.opensource.web.StandardAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
</bean>
```

**StandardAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java**

```
public class StandardAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter extends AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter    {
    @Override
    protected ServletRequestDataBinder createBinder(HttpServletRequest request, Object target, String objectName) throws Exception {
    MyServletRequestDataBinder dataBinder = new MyServletRequestDataBinder(target, objectName);
    return dataBinder;
   }
}
```

**MyServletRequestDataBinder .java**

```
public class MyServletRequestDataBinder extends ServletRequestDataBinder {

private MessageCodesResolver messageCodesResolver = new MyMessageCodesResolver();

@Override
public void initBeanPropertyAccess() {
   super.initBeanPropertyAccess();
   BindingResult bindingResult = super.getBindingResult();
   if(bindingResult instanceof AbstractBindingResult) {
       ((AbstractBindingResult)bindingResult).setMessageCodesResolver(messageCodesResolver);
   }
}

@Override
public void initDirectFieldAccess() {
  super.initDirectFieldAccess();
  BindingResult bindingResult = super.getBindingResult();
  if(bindingResult instanceof AbstractBindingResult) {
     ((AbstractBindingResult)bindingResult).setMessageCodesResolver(messageCodesResolver);
    }
 }
}
```

**MyMessageCodesResolver .java**

```
public class MyMessageCodesResolver extends DefaultMessageCodesResolver {

public static final String NOT_NULL_ERROR_CODE = "NotNull";

@Override
public String[] resolveMessageCodes(String errorCode, String objectName, String field, Class fieldType) {
   if(NOT_NULL_ERROR_CODE.equalsIgnoreCase(errorCode)) {
       String notNullErrorCode = errorCode + CODE_SEPARATOR + objectName + CODE_SEPARATOR + field;
       //notNullErrorCode = postProcessMessageCode(notNullErrorCode);
       return new String[] {notNullErrorCode};
    }
      return super.resolveMessageCodes(errorCode, objectName, field, fieldType);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following class to do JSR-303 and HibernateValidator bean validation manually with a Spring validator.  Perhaps it can be useful.

**BeanValidator.java**

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;

public class BeanValidator implements org.springframework.validation.Validator, InitializingBean {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BeanValidator.class.getName());

private Validator validator;

@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = validatorFactory.usingContext().getValidator();
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(target);
    for (ConstraintViolation<Object> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
        String propertyPath = constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString();
        String message;
        try {
            message = messageSource.getMessage(constraintViolation.getMessage(), new Object[]{}, Locale.getDefault());
        } catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
            log.error(String.format("Could not interpolate message \"%s\" for validator. "
                    + e.getMessage(), constraintViolation.getMessage()), e);
            message = constraintViolation.getMessage();
        }
        errors.rejectValue(propertyPath, "", message);
    }
}
}
```

**SpringMessageSourceMessageInterpolator.java**

```
import javax.validation.MessageInterpolator;
import org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSourceAware;
import org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException;

public class SpringMessageSourceMessageInterpolator extends ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator implements MessageInterpolator, MessageSourceAware, InitializingBean {

@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Override
public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context) {
    try {
        return messageSource.getMessage(messageTemplate, new Object[]{}, Locale.getDefault());
    } catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
        return super.interpolate(messageTemplate, context);
    }
}

@Override
public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context, Locale locale) {
    try {
        return messageSource.getMessage(messageTemplate, new Object[]{}, locale);
    } catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
        return super.interpolate(messageTemplate, context, locale);
    }
}

@Override
public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
    this.messageSource = messageSource;
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    if (messageSource == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("MessageSource was not injected, could not initialize "
                + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" p:basename="messages"/>

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageInterpolator">
        <bean class="com.company.utils.spring.SpringMessageSourceMessageInterpolator" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Example bean property**

```
@NotNull(message = "validation.mandatoryField")
private ClientGroup clientGroup;
```

**Example validation**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private BeanValidator validator;

    @RequestMapping("/foo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processFoo(ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        //...
        validator.validate(foo, result);
    }
}
```